# VSTO/WinWord Bind to Entering Event for DropDownListContentControl

Tags: c#, vsto, contentcontrol

I have a VSTO *addin* (not a template project), and I'd like to bind to the *Entering* event for any content controls manually added to the document, but can't figure out how to do the binding.

It's easy enough to find the appropriate Content Controls:

```
ActiveDoc.ContentControls.Cast<ContentControl>()
    .Where(cc => cc.Type == WdContentControlType.wdContentControlDropdownList)
```

*ContentControl* doesn't have any events at all, so it seems like I need to somehow obtain a *DropDownListContentControl* but I haven't been able to figure out how to get that from the ContentControl or any other source.

- You can't just cast ContentControl to DropDownListContentControl because there are no parents in common.
- I thought I might be able to find by using *dynamic*, but those don't support events.
- In *Template Projects* ContentControls are created using Globals.Factory.CreateDropDownListContentControl, but that doesn't seem to work for Addin projects.

I'm guessing there's something simple I'm missing, but hours of googling have been fruitless so far.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Guess I just didn't look long enough.  To do it you need to wrap your `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document` in a confusingly named `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Document` using this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Document doc 
    = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Addins.Globals.Application.ActiveDocument);
```

That class has a set of methods that will generate a wrapper with more events than the native controls.  So to get an event on any droplist, you do something like:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Document doc = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(ActiveDoc);
        foreach (ContentControl cc in ActiveDoc.ContentControls) {
            if (cc.Type == WdContentControlType.wdContentControlDropdownList) {
                var dropList = doc.Controls.AddDropDownListContentControl("MyControl");
                dropList.Tag = "MyControl";
                dropList.Entering += (sender, args) => {
                    var that = (DropDownListContentControl) sender;
                    Debug.Print("Entering: " + that.Tag);
                };
            }
        }
```

That's all there is to it, other than the controls themselves are pretty terrible from a usability perspective.

See [Host Items and Host Controls Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z4e3456%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
Document extendedDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Application.ActiveDocument);
int nIdx=0;
foreach(Word.ContentControl ctrl in Application.ActiveDocument.ContentControls)
{
ContentControl newCC = 

extendedDocument.Controls.AddContentControl(ctrl, "contentControlName"+nIdx.ToString());
    newCC.Entering += new ContentControlEnteringEventHandler( enteringEventHanlder);
    nIdx++;
}
```

it is code that coverting native content control to content control.
it maybe help you.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I've been finding I mostly hate content controls because their user experience is terrible, but I have to do them occasionally so this is a handy tip.